# Printing a pattern without a nested loop in PHP

Tags: php, regex, loops, nested, controls

The output to my code should be:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I'm currently using this code with a nested for loop to get the result.

```
for($lineNumber=1;$lineNumber<=5;$lineNumber++) {
    for($starCount=1;$starCount<=$lineNumber;$starCount++)         {
            echo("*");
    }
        echo("<br />");
}
```

I need to be able to get the same result without the nested for loop, and I'm stumped. The only thing I want to use is a single for loop. Nothing else. No ifs, switches, or other loops.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str = '';
for($lineNumber=1;$lineNumber<=5;$lineNumber++) {
    $str = $str . '*';
    echo $str;
    echo("<br />");
}
```

Using this string accumulator removes the need for a second loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
for($lineNumber=1;$lineNumber<=5;$lineNumber++) {
    echo str_repeat("*",$lineNumber);
    echo("<br />");
}
```

Comment: `str_repeat` still uses a loop internally. Doesn't this just hide that from the code without changing anything?

Comment: @CollinD i dont think so. its an internal loop. although the case is not this and he wants his code styling to be clearer.

Comment: I suppose you're right on that count. I just figured this was for homework (looks like a Freshman assignment haha)

Comment: I dont get what is `Freshman assignment` :D cause im not native english speaker (maybe its an idiom, maybe you are making fun of me .. :)) really?). Anyway I think my code is clearer and I think its the most important thing in coding.

Comment: not making fun of anyone, this just looks like an assignment that would be given as homework in a freshman level college programming course.

Answer (score 1):

Here is recursion version of it.

```
function inner($num)
{
    if ($num == 0)
        return;
    echo "*";
 
    inner($num - 1);
}
 
function outer($n, $i)
{
    if ($n == 0)
        return;
    inner($i);
    echo "<br/>";
    outer($n - 1, $i + 1);
}
 
$n = 5;
outer($n, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some examples of drawing a pyramid:

```
function print($n)
{
    //example 1
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $n; $x++) {
        for ($y = 1; $y <= $x; $y++) {
            echo 'x';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }

    // example 2
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $n; $x++) {
        for ($y = $n; $y >= $x; $y--) {
            echo 'x';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }

    // example 3

    for($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++) {
        for($y = 0; $y < $n - $x; $y++) {
            echo ' ';
        }
        for($z = 0; $z < $x * 2 +1; $z++) {
            echo 'x';
        }
        echo "\n";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of your requirement, that is fine to use with concat the string but what if string is not same as previous? here is solution for each patterns without any loop.

```
$i = 0;
a:
if($i <= 5){
    $j = 1;
    b:
    if($j<=$i){
        echo $i;
        $j++;
        goto b;
    }
    echo "<br/>";
    $i++;
    goto a; 
}
```

This will print

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

You can make any pattern like this.